# Delete rows based on cell criteria in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, object

I have a relatively simple question. Currently I have some code that is working well but not efficient. I have about 500 cost centres each with their own workbook which I have consolidated into a central repository (reference - Wb2 in code below). The code copies ranges from each open template (Wb1) into my consolidation (Wb2). Questions are enumerated after current code tagged below:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, wB As Workbook
    Dim rngToCopy1 As Range
    Dim rngToCopy2 As Range
    Dim rngToCopy3 As Range
    Dim rngToCopy4 As Range
    Dim rngToCopy5 As Range
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    For Each wB In Application.Workbooks
            If Not Left(wB.Name, 18) = "Consolidation Test" Then
            Set Wb1 = wB
            Exit For
            End If
    Next

        'Forecast Data
        With Wb1.Sheets(1)
        Set rngToCopy1 = .Range("A11:O11", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
            wb2.Sheets(7).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy1.Rows.Count, 15).Value = rngToCopy1.Value
            wb2.Sheets(7).Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy1.Rows.Count).Value = Sheets(3).Range("J1").Value

        'Planning (budget) Data
        With Wb1.Sheets(3)
        Set rngToCopy2 = .Range("A10:S10", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
            wb2.Sheets(8).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy2.Rows.Count, 19).Value = rngToCopy2.Value
            wb2.Sheets(8).Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy2.Rows.Count).Value = Sheets(3).Range("J1").Value

        'Travel Data
        With Wb1.Sheets(5)
        Set rngToCopy3 = .Range("A6:AA6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
            wb2.Sheets(9).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy3.Rows.Count, 27).Value = rngToCopy3.Value
            wb2.Sheets(9).Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy3.Rows.Count).Value = Sheets(3).Range("J1").Value

        'Vacancy Data
        With Wb1.Sheets(6)
        Set rngToCopy4 = .Range("A6:O6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
            wb2.Sheets(10).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy4.Rows.Count, 15).Value = rngToCopy4.Value
            wb2.Sheets(10).Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy4.Rows.Count).Value = Sheets(3).Range("J1").Value

        'Manpower Data
        With Wb1.Sheets(7)
        Set rngToCopy5 = .Range("A6:O6", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
            wb2.Sheets(11).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy5.Rows.Count, 15).Value = rngToCopy5.Value
            wb2.Sheets(11).Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy5.Rows.Count).Value = Sheets(3).Range("J1").Value



End Sub
```

I am now dealing with reiterations of template submissions so the exercise below becomes one of deleting as opposed to just copying and pasting. I'll need some sample code to check if Range("J1") on Sheets(3) appears in any of the other ranges I am pasting to:

```
With Wb1.Sheets(1)
        Set rngToCopy1 = .Range("A11:O11", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        End With
            wb2.Sheets(7).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy1.Rows.Count, 15).Value = rngToCopy1.Value
            wb2.Sheets(7).Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngToCopy1.Rows.Count).Value = Sheets(3).Range("J1").Value
```

In other words, what code would I use to check if J11 on sheet 3 first appears anywhere in column P on sheet 7 and if so delete? Only then should the paste operation run. The aim here is to delete data from any cost centres that have already been imported into my sheet.

Hope question and description of issue are clear? Reason I need a new post is because it is difficult for a novice to adapt already posted examples out there to my current code.

Thanks for your expertise!

Comment: The rule is to ask one question per thread. Perhaps you like to amend your post to contain only one question and ask another one to quench your additional thirst for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Each worksheet has a `Name` and a `CodeName`. By default both of them are the same. However, once the user changes the tab name they will be different. This is because the `CodeName` can't be changed from the spreadsheet interface. It takes access to VBA to change it. Therefore, if you refer to the worksheets by their `CodeName` in your code the user could give whatever name to the sheet and it wouldn't bother your code. Example.

Name = "MySheet"
CodeName = "Sheet1" (You can change this name in the VBE's property window)
Now refer to the sheet in the code as shown below.

```
Debug.Print Worksheets("MySheet").Name
Debug.Print Sheet1.Name
```

Comment: Ah I did think that this may be the case, however I also tried changing the WS reference to the default shown in VBE, so from ```With Wb1.Sheets(1)``` to ```With Wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")``` but still get same error. Can you be a little more specific with the application? Not sure if this would correct: ```With Wb1.Debug.Print Worksheets("MySheet").Name
Debug.Print Sheet1.Name
```

Comment: Try changing your `With` statement to `With WB1.Sheet1` as suggested by Variatus

Comment: Don't understand the error you get, unless it is in With Wb1.Debug.Print. Debug isn't a member of the workbook object. The code runs just as I published it without any "With". The print appears in the Immediate window.